# Loop recording of audio

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I would like to have an application that can record audio continuously and store in memory only last N seconds or minutes, so that I could press a key and save recently recorded audio into a file. It must not consume additional resources (memory and disk space) with time until I explicitly demand it.

Preferable but not mandatory:

- Save audio in an open compressed format (not raw)
- A button to immediately start listening saved file

Preferably desktop, preferably freeware.

References: [loop recording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_recording), [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: What OS(es)? (unfortunately I don't know anything like that for any OS but still good to mention preferred OS)

Comment: @NickWilde *Preferably desktop* (any)

Comment: @user3075942 "any" includes NetBSD, OS/2, ??? Better explicitly name the OSs you're after, even if multiple are OK. Or you might get some recommendations for [AmigaOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaOS) (don't laugh, last release of that was 11/2012!) :)

Comment: You could use a video program and only keep the audio for it.

Comment: @Izzy, as you can see, here are no suggestions now, so I am interested even in rare platforms if there is app for this task.

Comment: @AwesomeUser, it would be ok, but which video program supports loop recording?